# set very low values to zero in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy I have an array like

```
[0 +  0.5j, 0.25 + 1.2352444e-24j, 0.25+ 0j, 2.46519033e-32 + 0j]
```

what is the fastest and easiest way to set the super low value to zero to get

```
[0 +  0.5j, 0.25 + 0j, 0.25+ 0j, 0 + 0j]
```

efficiency is not the paramount.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Hmmm.  I'm not super-happy with it, but this seems to work:

```
>>> a = np.array([0 +  0.5j, 0.25 + 1.2352444e-24j, 0.25+ 0j, 2.46519033e-32 + 0j])
>>> a
array([  0.00000000e+00 +5.00000000e-01j,
         2.50000000e-01 +1.23524440e-24j,
         2.50000000e-01 +0.00000000e+00j,   2.46519033e-32 +0.00000000e+00j])
>>> tol = 1e-16
>>> a.real[abs(a.real) < tol] = 0.0
>>> a.imag[abs(a.imag) < tol] = 0.0
>>> a
array([ 0.00+0.5j,  0.25+0.j ,  0.25+0.j ,  0.00+0.j ])
```

and you can choose your tolerance as your problem requires.  I usually use an order of magnitude or so higher than

```
>>> np.finfo(np.float).eps
2.2204460492503131e-16
```

but it's problem-dependent.

Comment: I went with this because it handle both real and complex numbers, also its pretty easy and intuitive.

Comment: `ValueError: assignment destination is read-only` at `U.imag[abs(U.imag) < 0.0001] = 0.0j`

Answer (score 36):

To set elements that are less than `eps` to zero:

```
a[np.abs(a) < eps] = 0
```

There could be a specialized function that is more efficient.

If you want to suppress printing of small floats instead:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1+1e-10j])
print a # -> [ 1. +1.00000000e-10j]

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
print a # -> [ 1.+0.j]
```

Comment: That'll leave  `0.25 +1.23524440e-24j` alone, though.

Comment: @DSM: I've added variant that suppresses small floats on print (another possible interpretation of the OPs intent)

Answer (score 22):

By using the method round(n) of the array

```
np.array( [0 +  0.5j, 0.25 + 1.2352444e-24j, 
           0.25+ 0j, 2.46519033e-32 + 0j]  ).round(23)
```

Comment: This is a great function! I've been using numpy for years and never knew that arrays have a `round` function. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the [`numpy.isclose` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
>>> np.isclose([1e10,1e-7], [1.00001e10,1e-8])
array([True, False])
```

By asking if it is close to zero, it should work:

```
>>> np.isclose([1e10,0], [1.00001e-10,0])
array([False, True])
```

You can customise the `atol` (absolute tolerance, defaults to `1e-08`) and the `rtol` (relative tolerance, defaults to `1e-05`) parameters. You can then set `rtol=0` to only use the absolute tolerance.

Answer (score 5):

If all numbers have small imaginary parts, and you only want to suppress these then you can use

```
b=np.real_if_close(a)
```

Otherwise the suggestion by DSM is the way forward, i.e.

```
a.real[abs(a.real)<1e-13]=0
a.imag[abs(a.imag)<1e-13]=0
```

Answer (score -2):

```
diff = x-y
diff[diff>1.e-16]

Out[93]:
array([], dtype=float64)

diff[diff>1.e-18]

array([1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18,
       1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18,
       1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18,
       1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18, 1.73472348e-18,
       1.73472348e-18])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is not clear how this answers the question. Please add some explanation of the code you provide here and how it answers the question. Also format the code to be rendered as such (use the buttonbar in the edit window).