# Finding upper/lower triangular form of arbitrary matrix n*n - python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

every matrix can be written in upper or lower triangular form simply just by rotating the basis. Is there a simple routine in python (numpy) to do it? I was unable to find it and I cant believe that there is no such thing. To ilustrate it:

```
matrix = numpy.array([[a,b,c],
                      [d,e,f],
                      [g,h,i]])
```

to

```
matrix2 = numpy.array([[z,0,0],
                       [y,x,0],
                       [v,u,t]])
```

letters are floats. So how to make this change, but not simply just by zeroing numbers b, c and f, but by correct rotation of basis in the most simple way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition). Schur decomposition decomposes a matrix `A` as `A = Q U Q^H`, where `U` is an upper triangular matrix, `Q` is a unitary matrix (which effects the basis rotation) and `Q^H` is the Hermitian adjoint of `Q`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import schur

a = np.array([[ 1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.], [7., 8., 9.]])
u, q = schur(a) # q is the unitary matrix, u is upper triangular

repr(u)
# array([[  1.61168440e+01,   4.89897949e+00,   1.58820582e-15],
#        [  0.00000000e+00,  -1.11684397e+00,  -1.11643184e-15],
#        [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,  -1.30367773e-15]])
```

Comment: It worked, but in my case, decomposition was not  very fine. One number that should be zero was small non zero. But for my case it was sufficient precision.

Comment: Could this be a [floating point issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569528/python-float-to-int-conversion/6569657#6569657)? Matrix rotation normally involves a loss of precision. See the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419290/set-very-low-values-to-zero-in-numpy) for a possible solution.

Comment: Yes, I think thats the case. There was needed very small rotation, so elements of unitary matrix are small or close to one. But how I said it is suffiecient now. thanks.