# Does python have a similar function of "Chop" in Mathematica?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a big matrix with lots of elements extremely small, and I consider these elements as 0. In Mathematica, there is a function called [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html):

> `Chop[expr]` replaces approximate real numbers in `expr` that are close to
>   zero by the exact integer 0.
>
> Details
>
> - `Chop[expr,delta]` replaces numbers smaller in absolute magnitude than    `delta` by 0.
> - `Chop` uses a default tolerance of 10<sup>-10</sup>.

Therefore I want to ask if there is any function like this in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set very low values to zero in numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419290/set-very-low-values-to-zero-in-numpy)

Comment: @Julien you don't know if the poster is using numpy, though.

Comment: @pvg The question is about a big matrix in Python. Unless there is a very good reason, the standard advise would be to use numpy.

Comment: I highly recommend against using stuff like "Chop". It just messes up everything for you and does assumptions that are not safe in any application. Learn how to round values and do it right.

Comment: @BasSwinckels whatever the advice may be, what's being given here is not advice but a flag to close the question as a duplicate for which there is inadequate information. If someone would like to recommend numpy, more power to them. Flagging to close half-cocked, though, is not that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no built-in function for this, but you can easily create one yourself:

```
def chop(expr, *, max=0.3):
    return [i if i > max else 0 for i in expr]
```

Calling this would convert all numbers less than or equal to `0.3` to a `0`:

```
>>> chop([1.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.31])
[1.0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.31]
```

You should change the default value of `max` to something that suits your needs better, but you can always change it separately for individual calls too:

```
>>> chop([0.2, 0.3, 0.4], max=0.25)
[0, 0.3, 0.4]
>>> chop([0.3, 1, 2, 3], max=2)
[0, 0, 0, 3]
```

And if you want, you can convert negative numbers too! Either using the same distance from zero for both positive and negative numbers:

```
def chop(expr, *, max=0.3):
    return [i if abs(i) > max else 0 for i in expr]
```

Or by using two different limits:

```
def chop(expr, *, max=0.3, min=-0.3):
    if max < min:
        raise ValueError
    return [
        i if i > max or i < min else 0
        for i in expr
    ]
```

Comment: Your functions do the opposite, they replace with 0 elements that are far from zero. Also, they work for scalar values, while OP asked for a function that takes a matrix as an input.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that with numpy would be to use a masked array:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> def chop(expr, delta=10**-10):
...     return numpy.ma.masked_inside(expr, -delta, delta).filled(0)

>>> x = numpy.fft.irfft(numpy.fft.rfft([2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]))

>>> x
array([  2.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
         3.20493781e-17,  -4.44089210e-16,  -3.20493781e-17])

>>> chop(x)
array([ 2.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

If you really don't want to use numpy for some reason, then here's a function that works for scalar values, lists and multidimensional lists (matrices):

```
def chop(expr, delta=10**-10):
    if isinstance(expr, (int, float, complex)):
        return 0 if -delta <= expr <= delta else expr
    else:
        return [chop(x) for x in expr]
```

Comment: [There's already a good answer for this issue by using numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14419318/2505645), but OP has never mentioned that he's using numpy, so you shouldn't expect him to. And if it later turns out that he is, well then it's a duplicate question and should be closed.

Comment: Help pages say to "use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." I'm wondering which one of those applies to this answer.

Comment: @arekolek The tooltip when hovering over the downvote button says "This answer is not useful."  If Markus or anyone else believes this answer is not useful, they are free to downvote.

Comment: @NobodyNada I'm encouraging following the [community guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Am I not free to do that?