# how to keep some values untouched when using np.log() function

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([[45,2,3],[0,0,3],[7,89,9]])

x_1=x!=0

y=np.log((x+2), where=x_1)
```

Position (1,0) and (1,1) of y have values 9.88131e-323, why not just 2?
If I only take log of x, those values will be 0 (untouched)

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem on my machine. The code results in a correct result, both for `y` and `x_1`; If your problem is with tolerance, you can also do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419290/set-very-low-values-to-zero-in-numpy). Or clarify your question, with maybe some output from your machine.

Comment: Why don't you do simple `y=np.log(x, where=x_1)` and then add 2 to y wherever `x_1==True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Rishabh gave the numpy solution, here is a solution using the built in math library and a list comprehension (slower than numpy):

```
import math as m
import numpy as np


x=np.array([[45,2,3],[0,0,3],[7,89,9]])

y = np.array([[m.log(cell) if (cell != 0) else 2 for cell in row] for row in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` argument like this:

```
x=np.array([[45,2,3],[0,0,3],[7,89,9]])
zero_indices = x==0
non_zero_indices = x!= 0

y = np.log(x, where=non_zero_indices)
y = np.add(y, 2, where=zero_indices)
print(y)
```

output:

```
[[  0.00000000e+000   6.91973373e-310   6.91973641e-310]
 [  2.00000000e+000   2.00000000e+000   6.91973375e-310]
 [  6.91967302e-310   8.90000000e+001   3.95252517e-322]]
```